# Strange locale issue in the Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a url

```
<li><%= link_to "#{t('feed.add')}", feed_path(locale) %></li>
```

And the problem is, that after the registration, when I press this link for the first time it redirects me to the `mydomain.com/feed` and prints the next error:

```
"feed" is not a valid locale
```

in the

```
def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
end
```

But when I return back and clicks again it redirects me to the:

```
mydomain.com/en/feed
```

So, what is the problem of this strange problem?

**UPDATE**

```
devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
match '', :via => [:get], to: redirect("/#{I18n.locale}")
get '/en/youarethechampion' => "winners#winner"

get "/en/hook" => "feed#hook"
get '/thisvideonotfound' => 'feed#notFound'

get '/:locale/feed', to: 'feed#index', as: 'feed'
post '/:locale/feed/create', to: "feed#create"
get '/:locale/feed/new', to: "feed#new", as: 'feed_new'
get '/:locale/feed/destroy', to: "feed#destroy", as: 'feed_destroy'
get '/:locale/feed/edit', to: "feed#edit", as: 'feed_edit'
get '/:locale/feed/update', to: "feed#update", as: 'feed_update'

scope :path => "(:locale)", :locale => /en|ru/ do
  devise_for :users
end

match '/:locale/posts/search/', to: 'home#search', as: 'search', via: :get

get '/:locale/page/:page_slug' => 'home#about'
get '/:locale/:category/:id/', to: 'home#show', as: 'feed_show'
get '/:locale/:id/', except: 'search', to: 'home#by_category', as: 'category'
get '/:locale/posts/user/:name/', to: 'home#by_user', as: 'user'
get '/:locale/posts/tag/:tag/', to: 'home#by_tag', as: 'tag'
get '/:locale/pages/:page/', to: 'page#show', as: 'page'
post '/feed/:id/comments/', to: 'home#create_comment'
get '/:locale/', to: "home#index"
```

Comment: Post your routes file, locales file (e.g. en.yml) and application.rb

Comment: What is the value of `locale` when you do `feed_path(locale)`?

Comment: Also you can substitute `"#{t('feed.add')}"` with `t('feed.add')` - Not relevant to the answer though

Comment: @chocking_u I did add to my question

Comment: @MaxWilliams it doesn't matter, if I write even full url with the manual locale, for example en, it redirects again

Comment: So, you're saying that the value of `locale` is irrelevant in a situation when you pass it to a helper method and don't get the result you expect?  I'd say it's very relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like scenario after the registration: locale is `nil`, and this line

```
<li><%= link_to "#{t('feed.add')}", feed_path(locale) %></li>
```

make link to just `/feed`. (Try it print it in front of the link)

```
<li>
  Locale is <%= locale %>
  <%= link_to "#{t('feed.add')}", feed_path(locale) %>
</li>
```

Then routes think that /feed is belongs to this route

```
get '/:locale/', to: "home#index"
```

and it tries to set `feed` as the locale. It doesn't work! Then you move to another page you define "real" local through default_locale -> en.

```
I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
```

Comment: No, the locale is not empty, it equal to "en", but it still shows me this error

Comment: Ok, then post the application log within the error and also, post links path (Something like "path is <%= feed_path(locale) %>" inside the template).

Comment: it prints `/en/feed`. All is OK

Comment: Which line error does happen (you can find it in the logs)? The line where you set the I18n.localte? If yes – put a debug breakpoint here (e.g. using byebug gem) and try to figure out, what's inside params[:locale] and what happens when you set it up manually through console.